# Union or Intersection? Calculate uptime.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have this problems to solve. There are 4 areas. Each area has 4 switches.

For example, here are areas:

A1 A2 A3 A4 
B1 B2 B3 B4 
C1 C2 C3 C4 
D1 D2 D3 D4

Conditions:

1) If one switch in one area is down, the other areas can handle the corresponding load.

2) Even if one full area is down BUT all other 3 areas are fully up, they can handle the load.

3) If two corresponding switches in two independent areas go down, then the whole grid will go down. Which means, if A1 and B1 go down, the full grid is down. But if A1 and B2 go down, then the grid will not go down.

The question is to have the uptime of 99.999% how much time each single switch should be up in the year?

I solved it by doing this:

Let’s say, 
 
x = average uptime percentage of each switch

Unavailable would be = (1 – x)

When 3 switches are available = Given second switch is available * third is available * 4th = x^3

So, the availability target = When one switch is down the other three switches are still available

0.99999 = x + (1 - x) * x^3

x = 0.998173

(1 - 0.998173) * one year = 16 hours downtime per switch (given they go down independently)

Now what I am confused about is that in the equation do I need to consider 1 choose 4 since each area has 4 switches or is that information irrelevant as probability of available will include that? Also, I used union since a switch down in one area seems to be independent of other areas. Not sure if I should use intersection?

Answer (score 0):

Let's rename $A,B,C,D$ to $A_1,\dots,A_4$ and then A1 and B1 become $A_{11}$, $A_{21}$ etc.
Let $A_{11}$ be the event that A1 is *down*.

Then the event that the system is *down* is:
$$\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^4\bigcup_{\ell\ne k}\bigcup_{i=1}^4\bigcup_{j\ne i}\bigcup_{m=1}^4A_{ik}\cap A_{i\ell}\cap A_{jm}\right)\cup\bigcup_{i=1}^4\bigcup_{j\ne i}\bigcup_{k=1}^4 A_{ik}\cap A_{jk}$$
Let $p$ be the probability of any single $A_{ik}$ and assume these are independent events. Then by the Union Bound,
$$\Pr(\text{System is down})\le {4\choose 2}^2\cdot 4 p^3+{4\choose 2}\cdot 4 p^2=24p^2(6p+1)\le 10^{-5}.$$
If $p$ is small then $24(6p+1)\le 25$. So we need
$$25p^2<10^{-5}$$
$$p^2<\frac1{25\cdot 10^5}$$
$$p<\frac1{5\cdot\sqrt{10}\cdot 100}=0.00063245553$$
Thus, assuming 8765.81277 hours in a year, we have that
$$5.54\text{ hours}$$
hours of downtime per switch per year is **sufficient** to ensure 99.999% uptime for the system on average. But the exact answer may be larger (like your result of 16 hours).

Comment: how did you derive this? Pr(System is down)≤(42)2⋅4p3+(42)⋅4p2. Shouldn't it be 4 choose 1 instead of 4 choose 2?

Comment: Well you have to choose $k$ and $\ell$... that's two